# How to Identify which records have been boosted in solr search result

Tags: solr-boost

I have a requirement in my project to show a special tag on those records which have been boosted.

Use case : Client has created a boost rule to boost all soups of a particular brand. Now when user search term soup then all soups of the given brand will come first in the listing page due to boosting rule. Now the requirement is to show a special tag on those boosted soup products.

Approach tried : I analysed the score of each record and found that score of boosted records is added by the boost value i have given in the boost rule. But i am not getting any clear distinction so that i can identify those boosted records and apply special tag on them.

Looking for good suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

I got some advice in my question: [is there a way to tell if a result has been boosted in SOLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071089/is-there-a-way-to-tell-if-a-result-has-been-boosted-in-solr)

Basically, you can add debug=true as a parameter and then parse the debug info (it's painful but there's enough in there to go on), or you parse the result and if values meet the pre-determined special brand, then you know they'll have been boosted by SOLR